# How to create drop down hamburger menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

so I'm new to html/css and I'm working on a personal website. I'm having trouble creating a drop down hamburger menu. I have the header set up for mobile resize, but when I click on the hamburger icon the menu butts up again the main navigation. I'm trying to make it nestle under the main menu and have a width of 100%. As well as add the "x" symbol to close it when the user is done looking at it. I hope I explained it well enough, I'll post the [codepen link](http://codepen.io/ganimelover/pen/vyWqLx).

```js
 function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #EFF0EC
}

.header {
 padding-left: 30px;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 padding-top: 18px;
 padding-bottom: 18px;
}

h1 {
 font-size: 36px;
 font-family: Buenard, Times, serif;
 background-color: #FFFFFF
 float: left;
 display: inline;
}

ul.topnav {
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline;
 float: right;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}

li a {
 color: #000;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
 transition: 0.3s;
}

li a:hover {
 color: #80B198;
}

li {
 font-size: 22px;
 font-family: Lato, Arial sans-serif;
 padding: 10px 16px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: auto;
}

 ul. topnav li.icon {
 display: none;
}

/* Smartphone-size screens */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
 ul.topnav li {display: none;}
   ul.topnav li.icon {
    display: inline-block;
    }
    ul.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
   ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>

<div class="header">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
        <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
         <li><a class="active" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
         <li><a href="#about">About Me</a></li>
         <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></i>
         <li class="icon">
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
     </li>
  </ul>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: _"and have a width of 100%"_ Do you mean 100% as to parent element or 100% as to viewport?

Comment: Why don't you use Bootstrap? It has a easy component that do this job and it is also responsive. Do you know it?

Comment: @guest271314 100% to viewport, thanks

Comment: @lisarko8077 I'm not that familiar with it, I'm trying to learn hand-coding, but thank you, kittyCat helped solve my problem

Comment: thanks to all who commented, I was able to work it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, First of all you have to get your icon outside of the `ul` and position this `ul` as absolute in the mobile devices with a width of 100%. if click on the hamburger icon then it opens the menu and if you click on it again it closes it.

Here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/atulb29007/pen/YpmRaO?editors=1010) and below is the code.

Instead of having a cross. I think you should try one of these burger menu in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/designcouch/pen/Atyop). You can simply replace one of these with the `<div class="icon">`

```js
 function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #EFF0EC
}

.header {
 padding-left: 30px;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 padding-top: 18px;
 padding-bottom: 18px;
  position:relative;
}

h1 {
 font-size: 36px;
 font-family: Buenard, Times, serif;
 background-color: #FFFFFF
 float: left;
 display: inline;
}

ul.topnav {
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline;
 float: right;
 margin: auto;
  margin-right:50px;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}

li a {
 color: #000;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
 transition: 0.3s;
}

li a:hover {
 color: #80B198;
}

li {
 font-size: 22px;
 font-family: Lato, Arial sans-serif;
 padding: 10px 16px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: auto;
}

div.icon {
 position:absolute;
  top:30px;
  right:20px;
}

/* Smartphone-size screens */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  ul.topnav{
    position:absolute;
    top:60px;
    left:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    background-color:white;
  }
 ul.topnav li {display: none;}
   ul.topnav li.icon {
    display: inline-block;
    }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>

<div class="header">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
        <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
         <li><a class="active" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
         <li><a href="#about">About Me</a></li>
         <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
         <div class="icon">
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
      </div>
    </div>

</body>
```